# undefined is not a function (evaluating navigate(screen))

Tags: react-native

1.Can't navigate to the screen from inside the content component to the mention screen

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {View,Text,Button,Image,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen'


export default class DrawerScreen extends Component{
static navigationOptions= ({navigation}) =>({
}); 
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.Image}
            source={require('../images/defalut.png')} />
            <Text> @username </Text>
            <View>
             <Icon
               name='ios-settings'
               color='#000'
               size={14}
               />
            <Button
      onPress={() =>{
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation.navigate;
       navigate('SettingsScreen')}}
      color="orange"        
      title="Settings"
/>
          </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    Image:{
        width:70,
        height:80, 
        borderRadius:40
    }   
});
```

- Navigating to screen from contentComponent in drawer isnot working using the props function it still shows the error
- and the still it can't navigate to the screen

Comment: `it still shows the error`: What does the error say? Can you update the question to add the error and your router definition?

Comment: Try `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation` inside of your `onPress`. What you have right now (`const { navigate } = this.props.navigation.navigate;`) evaluates to `this.props.navigation.navigate.navigate` (see two `navigate`).

Comment: undefined is not a function evaluating navigate settingscreen

Comment: Still same error ....

Comment: am not using it in router and not in app.js or index.js simply in auth flw i have created an contentcomponent screen in drawer and from drawercontentcomponent screen i want to navigate to other screen

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot yet add comments, so I have to use an answer.

Have you defined a route for your DrawerScreen Component? 
Otherwise it will not get the navigation as a prop, afaik.

Comment: my drawerscreen is in contentcomponent of drawernavigator and i m not using any route funtion simply i have used all navigation function in auth flw

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation.navigate;
navigate('SettingsScreen')}}
```

You are trying to take the navigate function from the navigate function.

What is the problem with using just:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen');
```

Comment: undefined is not an object evaluating this props navigation navigate this error popup